# For loop not working - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

This code isn't working: Help! It is only displaying as "no answers left", not anything else and that is displaying that I have only 0 attempts left. I am new to Javascript and need some support, I think the "for" loop isn't working. I can only try out this code once, then the page crashes.

```
function mathCheck() {
                var inputValues1 = document.mathGuesser.mGuesser.value;
                var attempts;
                for (attempts = 3; attempts >= 0; ) {
                    if (inputValues1 === 'y = 2x - 3' || inputValues1 === 'y=2x-3') {
                        document.getElementById("answer").style.color = "Green";
                        document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "<span>" + "Correct" + "</span>";                     
                    }
                    else if (inputValues1 === ' ' || inputValues1 === '') {
                        document.getElementById("answer").style.color = "Black";
                        document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "<span>" + "Please enter text" + "</span>";
                    }
                    else {
                        document.getElementById("answer").style.color = "Red";
                        document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "<span>" + "Incorrect" + "</span>";
                        document.getElementById("attempts").innerHTML = attempts;
                        attempts--;
                    }
                }
                document.getElementById("answer").style.color = "Black";
                document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "No attempts left";
            }
```

Comment: your for loop is wrong it probably should be " for (attempts = 0; attempts <= 3; attempts++ )  "

Comment: `for (attempts = 3; attempts >= 0; ???) {`

Comment: Your loop never exits

Comment: @pedro nope that wouldnt run at all

Comment: There is an issue with the loop but it is not the question. Can you print inputValues1 to make sure it's the right value?

Comment: Your loop will never exit unless there is an incorrect answer. Presumably you want a `break;` statement at the end of the first two conditional blocks.

Comment: The issue is that it only displays `No attempts left`, and it's really annoying and anytime I enter the value of `y=2x-3` the program just freezes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general the algorithm you came up with is working, e.g.:

```
for (attempts = 3; attempts >= 0; ) {
  const answer = prompt("Answer to live?");
  if(answer === "42"){
    alert("correct!");
  } else {
    attempts--;
    alert(attempts + " attempts left");
  }
}
alert("you lost :(");
```

But that scenario does work because weve got synchronous code. Waiting for the user to enter the right answer is not synchronous but rather asynchronous. So in your case it will check the answer three times before the user is even to  able to enter the right answer and in case the right answer was entered the loop runs forever so fast, that it freezes the browser. To solve this you need a state (remaining) and handle the different cases on every click:

```
var attenpts = 3;

function mathCheck() {
  if(attempts <= 0)
    return answer("Your tries are up!", "red");

  var inputValues1 = document.mathGuesser.mGuesser.value;
  if (inputValues1 === 'y = 2x - 3' || inputValues1 === 'y=2x-3') {
     answer("Correct", "green");       
  } else if (inputValues1 === ' ' || inputValues1 === '') {
     answer("Please enter your answer!", "black");
  } else {
     answer("Incorrect!", "red");
     document.getElementById("attempts").innerHTML = attempts;
     attempts--;
  }
}

function answer(text, color){
   const el = document.getElementById("answer");
   el.innerHTML = "<span>" + text + "</span>";
   el.style.color = color;
}
```

Comment: Good, but it's not displaying the **You're tries are up** when it's at 0.

Comment: @flatboulder oh right, i messed up the variable names ... :/

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what you're trying to do, you should specify what the function aims to do in your question, and provide details of the issue, however this is the format of a For loop:

```
for(var foo = 0; foo < 10; foo++)
```

So your for loop should look like so:

```
for (attempts = 3; attempts >= 0; attempts++)
```

This makes "attempts" increment by exactly one on each iteration of the loop.
Note that the last part is up to you, since your variable starts at 3, and loops while greater than or equal to 0, I'm going to assume you want to decrement, so you could use: attemps--, attempts-=1..